# Merge multiple Typescript files into one single JS files including tree shaking

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I would like to merge all my TS files of my application from an entry-point including all the dependent files (Tree shaking) for that entry-point.

In my present application index.ts is the entry point which has dependency on uuid npm package and time other file of my own code. And Time file has dependency on moment-timezone npm package.

I want all the code in JS in one single file including code of npm packages uuid, moment-timezone, for a stand alone application.

The webpack config from below i am able to get everything in one file but it is wrapped as some functions with webpack code also. I want everything in one single file so that i can have code as i have written.

Such as

```
class {}
class {}
class {}

funcion() {}
```

etc.

my TS- config file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    //"module": "amd",  
    "module": "es6",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    
     "sourceMap": false,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
     //"outFile": "./out.js",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
     "outDir": "dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */

     "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
  
    /*webpack*/
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": [
      "./src/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

my Webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle-test.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist1'),
  },
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'webworker',
  devtool: false
};
```

my Index.ts:

```
import { Time } from "./Time";
const { v4: id } = require('uuid');

export class Index {

    time: Time;


    public constructor() {
        this.time = new Time();
    }

    public generate(): string {
        return id();
    }

    public unauthorizedException(): void {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
}
class UnauthorizedException extends Error {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = "UnauthorizedException";
    }
}


var utils;
function util() {
    utils = new Index();
    return utils;
};

export { util };
```

My small version of bundle file from webpack compilation (whole file is pretty large):

Removed it causing issues in loading the page

Answer (score 0):

Rollup iife format provides a near format of the above not the same.

https://rollupjs.org/

With plugins typescript, commonjs, nodeResolve.